# Resharper file path hints/verification for Strings that represent a file path

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, resharper, web-essentials

Resharper auto-completes/hints and verifies file paths when I am in a Razor template and type an image tag's src attribute. However, throughout my ASP.net application I have many methods that take a String that represents a path to a file. Is there any way that I can enable this same verification and auto-completion functionality for those strings?

[image: file path help in Resharper]

I am using VS 2013, Resharper 8.1, along with ASP.net MVC, and Web Essentials.

Comment: No way that I'm aware of, but that does sound like a handy feature.

Comment: Yes, part of the issue is I don't think that ASP has a class to represent the concept of an application path, so my method signatures only contain String types. If there were something like a VirtualPath type of String, Resharper could look for that and apply auto-completion there. At the very least, it would be nice if they extended the `@Url.Content(String)` method to have this auto-completion functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're asking can be solved by applying ReSharper's [Code Annotations](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Code_Analysis__Code_Annotations.html) to your helpers! I recently recorded a webinar with JetBrains called [ReSharper Secrets](http://blog.jetbrains.com/blog/2014/02/19/webinar-recording-and-qa-resharper-secrets/), where I talk in depth about Annotations, and actually show how to do the very thing you're asking! (around 32 minutes in)

Basically, you need to apply the `[PathReference]` attribute on the string parameter of your helper methods that represents the path, and you're done! I wrote a blog post about how to do it, you can read it [here](http://hmemcpy.com/2013/02/more-fun-with-resharper-annotations-in-asp-net-mvc/).

Comment: Wow. That is very cool. Thanks! I'm now getting path verification, but the auto-completion still isn't working for some reason. I can only get so far as the tilde and then it won't auto-complete any more fragments of the path. Any idea what's going on? It's the same behavior I get using `@Url.Content()`, but when I auto-complete on the `src` attribute of an `img` tag, I get the correct behavior (see image in OP).

Comment: @RyanNorbauer I'm not quite sure, does the completion work if you invoke it manually, i.e. Ctrl-Space? Could you maybe post one example of such an extension?

Comment: Hmm. Interesting. Using Ctrl+Space works! It is just slightly different behavior than with `<img src="{filename}">`, so I was confused as to how to invoke the auto-completion, but using the keystroke works perfectly and solves my problem. Thanks again, Igal!